# Proper asymmetric file encryption in Go

Tags: encryption, go, public-key-encryption

I need a way to allow multiple people encrypting various files but only one party been able to read them all. I wrote a program in Go by following various online examples but at some point I got the following error:

`Error from encryption: crypto/rsa: message too long for RSA public key size`

Is RSA the wrong way to go? Is it ok if I break the file into multiple chunks and encrypt them? Is there an asymmetric block cipher that I can easily use?

I read the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404757/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-plain-text-with-a-rsa-keys-in-go) and it is said that RSA is not the proper way to go.

Can you also provide with an example?

Comment: If this is a serious project with substantial users you really need to get a cryptographic domain expert involved, security is very hard to get correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using GPG and my service has one unique private key and I share the public one with my users.

Answer (score 0):

If you need public key asymmetric encryption for data larger than the key size you need to use hybrid encryption. Essentially this is how HTTPS works.

[Hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) is where the data is encrypted with symmetric key encryption such as AES and that key is encrypted with asymmetric key encryption such as RSA or EC ([Elliptic Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography)) Cryptography.

**Do not** break the file into multiple chunks and encrypt them.

Comment: Hi! Do you thing something like PGP would do the job for me? I see that golang supports a PGP implementation in its core library: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp